# How to Achieve AsyncTask PublishProgress Effect in CursorLoader Android

Tags: android

Good day, As we all know, with AsyncTask, We get the PublishProgress() method which can be used to periodically update the main UI thread. This is particularly useful when your loading plenty images from an sdcard or anywhere and displaying them as each has finished loading.

How can you achieve the same task of periodically updating the UI with CursorLoader(with respect to loading images)?.. or is the CursorLoader so fast enough that only using a Progress dialog will suffice?

i am thinking you can use handlers but not too sure how. Thank you

Comment: no one has an idea.. guess thats why we still have AsyncTask around for things like these, right?.. ;)